# Data from Webservice Value null of type cannot be converted to JSONArray

Tags: java, android, json, multithreading, android-asynctask

I'm trying to display items from a database, that database is located on the internet. I'm getting the error *Value null of type org.json.JSONObject$1 cannot be converted to JSONArray* and I'm not entirely sure how to fix this. I've provided my LogCat information and the associated class. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

APIConnector Class

```
package com.example.mywebsite.com;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class APIConnector {

    public JSONArray GetAllCustomers(){

            String url = "http://mywebsite.com/getState.php";

            HttpEntity httpEntity = null;

            try{

                     DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                     HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                     HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

                     httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

            } catch(ClientProtocolException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();

            } catch(IOException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }


            JSONArray jsonArray = null;

            if(httpEntity !=null){
                    try{
                            String entityResponse = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

                            Log.e("Entity Response : ", entityResponse);

                            jsonArray = new JSONArray(entityResponse);
                    } catch(JSONException e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch(IOException e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                    }
            }

            return jsonArray;
    }


    public JSONArray GetCityDetails(String StateID) {

            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            String url = "http://mywebsite.com/getCity.php?StateID="+URLEncoder.encode(StateID);

            HttpEntity httpEntity = null;

            try{

                     DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                     HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                     HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

                     httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();


            } catch(ClientProtocolException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();

            } catch(IOException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }

            JSONArray jsonArray = null;

            if(httpEntity !=null){
                    try{
                            String entityResponse = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

                            Log.e("Entity Response Dude: ", entityResponse);

                            jsonArray = new JSONArray(entityResponse);
                    } catch(JSONException e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch(IOException e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                    }
            }
            return jsonArray;
    }





}
```

LogCat Information

```
09-20 13:04:01.399: W/KeyCharacterMap(4784): No keyboard for id 0
09-20 13:04:01.399: W/KeyCharacterMap(4784): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
09-20 13:04:03.359: E/Entity Response Dude:(4784): null
09-20 13:04:03.359: W/System.err(4784): org.json.JSONException: Value null of type org.json.JSONObject$1 cannot be converted to JSONArray
09-20 13:04:03.359: W/System.err(4784):         at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:107)
09-20 13:04:03.359: W/System.err(4784):         at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:91)
09-20 13:04:03.359: W/System.err(4784):         at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:103)
09-20 13:04:03.359: W/System.err(4784):         at com.example.mywebsite.com.APIConnector.GetCityDetails(APIConnector.java:100)
09-20 13:04:03.359: W/System.err(4784):         at com.example.mywebsite.com.CityDetailsActivity$GetAllStates.doInBackground(CityDetailsActivity.java:64)
09-20 13:04:03.359: W/System.err(4784):         at com.example.mywebsite.com.CityDetailsActivity$GetAllStates.doInBackground(CityDetailsActivity.java:1)
09-20 13:04:03.369: W/System.err(4784):         at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
09-20 13:04:03.369: W/System.err(4784):         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
09-20 13:04:03.369: W/System.err(4784):         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
09-20 13:04:03.369: W/System.err(4784):         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
09-20 13:04:03.369: W/System.err(4784):         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
09-20 13:04:03.369: W/System.err(4784):         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

Comment: You are trying to read a jsonArray value but instead you are catching a null value, as a jsonObject.

Answer (score 0):

looks like entityResponse has JSON object at the top and you are trying to parse it as JSONArray

org.json.JSONObject$1 cannot be converted to JSONArray

so insted of
jsonArray = new JSONArray(entityResponse);

try
JSONObject obje=new JSONObject(entityResponse);

Comment: I appreciate the help but when I changed my entire method (GetCityDetails) to return a JSONObject I'm getting the error message **Value null of type org.json.JSONObject$1 cannot be connverted to JSONObject**

Comment: what is this line printing in logcat: Log.e("Entity Response : ", entityResponse);

Comment: in my first method (GetAllCustomers) my "Enity Response" is `09-21 08:07:34.149: E/Entity Response :(2025): [{"state":"Alabama"},{"state":"Alaska"},{"state":"Arizona"},{"state":"Arkansas"}]` In my second method (GetCityDeatails) my "Enity Response Dude" is "null"